# Proof of Folland Lemma 3.2

Tags: measure-theory

On Folland page 86 Lemma 3.2 states that the union of any countable family of positive sets is positive, and the proof is as follows:

> If $P_1, P_2, ... $ are positive sets let $Q_n = P_n \setminus \bigg( \bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1}P_i\bigg)$.  Then $Q_n \subset P_n$ so $Q_n$ is positive.  Hence if $E \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}P_i$ then
>
> $$
> \nu(E) = \nu \bigg(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}E \cap Q_i \bigg) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\nu(E \cap Q_i) \geq 0
> $$

My question is on the last equality, I assume that we know the infinite sum is greater than $0$ since each of the terms $\nu(E \cap Q_i)$ will be greater than $0$, but we only know that each $Q_i$ is a positive set and not necessarily $E$.

How do we know that for each $i$ that $\nu(E \cap Q_i) \geq 0$?

In other words how do we know that $E \cap Q_i$ is a positive set?

Comment: $Q_n = P_n \setminus \bigg( \bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1}?\bigg)$

Answer (score 1):

Let $E$ be measurable and $E \subset \cup_{n=1}^{\infty}P_n$.

Then $E \cap Q_i \subset Q_i \subset P_i$ for all $i = 1,2,\ldots$. Now $Q_i$ is measurable for all $i=1,2,\ldots$ since it is constructed from complements and unions of measurable sets, and since $E$ is measurable, $E \cap Q_i$ is measurable for all $i=1,2,\ldots$. Since $E \cap Q_i \subset P_i$ then $E \cap Q_i$ is positive for all $i=1,2,\ldots$.